# Whether phase congruency and phase coherence terms are same or different?

Tags: signal, fourier, imageprocessing, phase

I am studying the importance of phase in signal.Can anybody explain what is phase congruency ?

Also,I am confused between terms i.e. phase congruency and phase coherence. Whether phase congruency and phase coherence are one and the same or different

Answer (score 1):

Phase congruency is where the phases of a quadrature filter responses at different scales are similar.

Some links:

- http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/OWENS/LECT7/node2.html
- http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/research/pkpapers/phasecorners.pdf

Papers:

- Oppenheim, A. V., & Lim, J. S. (1981). The importance of phase in signals.
- Kovesi, P. (1995). Image Features From Phase Congruency.
- Kovesi, P. (1996). Invariant measures of image features from phase information.
- Kovesi, P. (1997). Symmetry and asymmetry from local phase.
- Kovesi, P. (1999). Image features from phase congruency.
- Kovesi, P. (2002). Edges are not just steps.
- Kovesi, P. (2003). Phase congruency detects corners and edges.
- Morrone, M. C., & Burr, D. C. (1988). Feature detection in human vision: a phase-dependent energy model.
- Morrone, M. C., & Owens, R. a. (1987). Feature detection from local energy.
- Perona, P., & Malik, J. (1990). Detecting and Localizing Edges Composed of Steps, Peaks and Roofs.
- Reisfeld, D. (1996). Constrained phase congruency: simultaneous detection of interest points and of their orientational scales.
- Robbins, B., & Owens, R. (1997). 2D feature detection via local energy.
- Venkatesh, S., & Owens, R. (1990). On the classification of image features.